# WatiN RunScript fails in FireFox

Tags: c#, firefox, watin

I have some WatiN tests in IE that I'm porting to FireFox (3.6, 4.0 not supported yet I think) and I have an error in the following code:

```
var browser = new FireFox(_baseUri);
browser.RunScript("alert('hello');")
```

Even though it runs fine in IE. I get the error "{"Error sending last message to jssh server: ReferenceError: alert is not defined"}".

I've tried lots of variations without any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed

```
browser.RunScript("window.alert('hello');");
```

D'oh!